# Not able to assign Reponse type object to Response type variable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I'm getting the following error.

> Argument of type 'Response' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Response'.
>   Property 'body' is missing in type 'Response'.

The code I'm running relies on observables.

```
public register(reporter: Reporter): Observable<Response> {

  const content = JSON.stringify(reporter);
  const headers = new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" });
  const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  const userUrl = env.Url + "user";
  const passwordUrl = env.Url + "PasswordClaim/" + reporter.Id;

  const observable = new Observable<Response>(_ => {
    this.http
      .post(userUrl, content, options)
      .subscribe(result => this.http
          .get(passwordUrl)
          .subscribe(result => _.next(result), error => _.error(error)),
      error => _.error(error));
  });

  return observable;
}
```

Before, we used weakly typed observable, which works but isn't as proper and neat as I wish. So, I hovered over *result* and got that it's of type *Response*. Using that, however, seems to produce this weird error message.

I can imagine that it's different classes named the same way and placed in separate namespaces. However, googling gave me no confirmation of it, let alone a suggested solution on how to resolve it. There are [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35205040/1525840) to omit the typing all together but that's not a part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing here is returning an Observable of an Observable. Your method should be typed along the lines of

```
public register(reporter: Reporter): Observable<Reporter> {}
```

Or

```
public register(reporter: Reporter): Observable<any> {}
```

Maybe you could try that and see the result ?

**EDIT** I have a better grip of your problem now.

Try something like this

```
public register(reporter: Reporter): Observable<Response> {

  const content = JSON.stringify(reporter);
  const headers = new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" });
  const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  const userUrl = env.Url + "user";
  const passwordUrl = env.Url + "PasswordClaim/" + reporter.Id;

  return this.http
    .post(userUrl, content, options)
    .flatMap(result => this.http.get(passwordUrl));
}
```

Basically, an HTTP call will return a response. By using subscribe, you actually manage the response. What you are doing is treating the response, the returning a new, custom response.

What I do instead, is making two calls with `flatMap`, and returning the result of the last call.

**EDIT 2** Here is the complete function :

```
public register(reporter: Reporter): Observable<Response> {

  let ret = {};

  const content = JSON.stringify(reporter);
  const headers = new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" });
  const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  const userUrl = env.Url + "user";
  const passwordUrl = env.Url + "PasswordClaim/" + reporter.Id;

  return this.http
    .post(userUrl, content, options)
    .flatMap(result => {
      ret['result1'] = result;
      return this.http.get(passwordUrl).map(r => ret['result2'] = r);
    });
}
```

Comment: Allow me an hour or two to process it. It still feels confusing that *Response* can't be assinged to *Response*. I also realized that I **do want** to return *Response*, not *Credentials* because I might want to read the status text and error code in the future. Why is it that "type X is not assignable to type X" is possible as an error message at all?! And +1 for code sample.

Comment: Actually I've made a mistake, my way is actually returning a Response ! I have deleted my previous comment to avoid any mistake.

Comment: You need to type your method as `Observable<Response>`, and not Credentials. Then, you can get the data with `response.json()` and the code with `response.status`. This way, you have all you want !

Comment: It took me a while to grasp your suggestion properly but now I'm starting to see your point. The thing is that I need to subscribe to the first call - the post because then I'll get both *result* **and** *error*. Simply mapping flat doesn't do it, seemingly. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The flatMap allows the calls to chain. What exactly should your response made of ?

Comment: Not sure if I'm getting the point here. I need to react on the error event in the post in one way. I need to react to the error event in the get in another. By using flat mapping I seemed to lose the error event and got no response in my GUI. (Not sure how to check what my response is made of, please advise.)

Comment: You will check your error into your component, where you call the service, with `this.myservice.register(...).subscribe(response => {}, error => console.log(error))`. To get the data from the first  call, create a variable in your service that you will return ! I'm on phone right now but I can make you a code snippet tomorrow

Comment: Cool. I'll give it one more whack before hitting the bed. You're welcome to post a sample in case I'm getting stuck on annoyance or something.   :)

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't even thought about that during the weekend ! here is the complete function that you can find in the second edit. You get both http results, containing the data & status, and in your components, you can handle the error in the subscribe !